# Using beautifulsoup4 to Make a Distinction Between Two Identical Tag Contents Based on Siblings

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm currently attempting to grab text from an html element in a web page using beautifulsoup4. My issue is there is an exactly identically named element elsewhere in the page. It goes something like this.

```
<div class="class">
  <span class="1"></span>
  <span class="value">text I want</span>
</div>
<div class="class">
  <span class="2"></span>
  <span class="value">text I DON'T want</span>
</div>
```

I am attempting to return "**text I want**". Now, the nice thing here is that you do have that class difference between the siblings -- the first one's sibling has class "1," and the second one's sibling has class "2" -- but I have no idea how to actually bear that distinction out in the code. Can someone experienced in bs4 help me out with this?

Mind you, I am using CSS Selectors to get the elements I want, so if we could use that to get the element that contains the text, then all the better.

Example of how I'm finding elements

```
soup.select("span[id='identifier']")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPATHs:

```
 soup.find('span[@class="1"]').next_sibling
```

Using CSS:

```
soup.select("span.1 ~ .value")
```

I believe both of those should work. Otherwise, I would recommend checking the documentation [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#sibling-generators)

Comment: I'd upvote but it's not letting me. Mods negged me hard when I asked a question they didn't like. Sorry man.

Comment: No problem at all. Are you able to accept the answer at least?

Comment: Yeah I think I just did.